# How do you provide a GoogleApiClient dependency with Dagger2?

Tags: dagger-2, android-googleapiclient

I've started using Dagger2 to manage dependencies and I'm trying to understand how I can use DI to provide a singleton GoogleApiClient. The motivations for this are:

- **reduce boilerplate code**: multiple Activities & Fragments require a GoogleApiClient
- **improve testability**: currently these Activities and Fragments are not well tested

I want to provide a Singleton GoogleApiClient at the Application scope.

**How do you handle callbacks?** Whether you choose an [auto-managed or manually-managed connection](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client), there are some callbacks that must be handled:

- GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks (manual only)
- GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener (both)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the injection to create the client

```
 @Provides
    @Singleton
    GoogleApiClient providesGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
            return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
```

And then manage the call backs on your activity

```
@Inject GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;



if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {  mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(this);            mGoogleApiClient.registerConnectionFailedListener`(this);
}
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Are `onResume()` and `onPause()` the correct place to register/unregister the listener?

Comment: Your example provider method creates the client (not just the builder, as your wording suggests).

Comment: @sidecarcat Yes you are right, it provides the client.  The disconnect is normally is called on onStop() and onStart you can call connect

Comment: Just want to add that if you wont to avoid boilerplate onStart/onStop you can just pass lifecycle ApiClient wrapper and let handle it there.

Comment: I am getting googleApiClient is not initialized, any ideas?