# Injection of GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-2

I want to inject to instances of Google api client in different parts of my project however I haven't manage to make it work.

```
@Provides @Named("geodata_api")
    @Singleton
    GoogleApiClient providesGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
            return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .build();
        }
```

---

```
  @Provides @Named("location_api")
    @Singleton
    GoogleApiClient providesGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(providesContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: No question marks "?", you are not asking a question. More detail needed. what exactly is failing and what diagnostics are given?

Comment: The same question was asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35972868/1837367

Comment: "i haven't manage to make it work" -> *What* doesn't work? Could you post the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Dagger wouldn't be able to provide the callbacks, since the callbacks are implementation details, not dependencies -- and the callbacks are typically set before building the client (see option 2 below for more on callbacks).

One option would be to have Dagger provide the `GoogleApiClient.Builder`, and then your implementation must finish the chain by setting the callbacks and calling `build()`:

```
@Provides
@Named("location_api")
GoogleApiClient.Builder provideLocationClient(Context context) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API);
}

@Provides
@Named("geodata_api")
GoogleApiClient.Builder provideGeodataClient(Context context) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API);
}
```

Note the changes:

1. `@Named(..)` is already a scope, so you should drop the `@Singleton` -- it's not needed.
2. The two provider methods need to be named differently (`provideLocationClient`, `provideGeodataClient`)
3. Instead of returning the `GoogleApiClient`, the module is returning a `GoogleApiClient.Builder`.

Now to use that dependency, you would inject the builder, and then attach your callbacks and build the client:

```
@Inject @NamedScope("location_api") GoogleApiClient.Builder mLocationClientBuilder;

...

mComponent.inject(this);
mClient = mLocationClientBuilder.<addCallbacks(...)>.build();
mClient.connect();
```

When mocking this builder using your unit test mocking framework, one thing you'll have to do is keep a reference to the callback, and invoke the `onConnected(Bundle)` callback method when `connect()` is called.

---

Another option is to provide the `GoogleApiClient` as you were, but then you have to remember to register your callbacks before connecting, and you have to remember to unregister those callbacks when you're done (to prevent a memory leak). See [GoogleApiClient#registerConnectionCallbacks()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#registerConnectionCallbacks(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks))